# Thermal exfoliation of graphite oxide

Tags: graphene

I have been reading up on the production methods of graphene, and one that I found interesting in particular was the thermal exfoliation of graphite oxide. From what I gather the basic idea is that the oxides are located in between the graphene layers of graphite, and that you then heat the material up, causing gasses such as CO and CO<sub>2</sub> to form in between the layers. This sort of lifts the layers from each other, and then they become separate. However, what I don't get is why the layers don't simply re-aggregate on top of each other.

The reason I wonder about this is because thermal exfoliation is done (at least it is possible to do so) without putting the graphite oxide in a liquid or anything; it can just be done 'dry'. Now liquid exfoliation, on the other hand, is based on using ultrasound to separate graphite layers, which are submerged in a fluid with surface energies such that it is unfavorable for the graphite to re-aggregate. 
So is it simply that this re-aggregation is not troublesome when your graphite is not in a liquid? I suppose if this is the case, then the only reason for liquid exfoliation is if it is more efficient/effective/cheap than doing the thermal version.